# serialize / deserialize linq to objects query

Tags: .net, linq-to-objects

I have a linq to objects query, say:

```cs
  var q = from Record as Record
          in ParseResults
          where Record.Fields.Any
          select Record.Sequence;
```

I want to serialize it in xml and then deserialize it back into `q`.

I don't want to make my own Linq provider, I would just like to have some functions using the Linq to Objects provider.

Also note, `q` will be a relatively simple query, but the return type could be anything. I mean, the generic arguments of the enumerable type.

I also don't want to use a library, because those go down and get abandoned. The simpler the better, but I want to support from, select, joins, where, groupby, and aggregates.

Comment: Do you want to serialize the query or the results you get from evaluating the query?

Comment: Don't thinks it's possible. (at least without additional libraries or your own LINQ implementation).

Comment: There is nothing like serialization/deserialization linq query to query. Could you be so kind and elablorate what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, I guess it will be possible after I post my solution (assuming no one else solves it).

Comment: Look at [Serialize.Linq](https://github.com/esskar/Serialize.Linq). Never tried it myself, but looks promising.

Comment: @MaciejLos, thanks but that usually leads to short circuit answers, so I feel I should refrain from that.

Comment: @user3411327, over the years, I have learned not to depend on the libraries of others, because they cannot be relied upon to be maintained and stay up.